# $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(\log_x 2^k )*\log_x (2^k*2))}=\frac{4n}{n+1} $

Tags: logarithms

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ being the following function:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(\log_x 2^k )\log_x (2^{k+1}))}$$
The goal is to find $x$ such that:
$$f(x)=\frac{4n}{n+1}$$

This looks and definitely is really simple, and yet I can't figure out where's my mistake.

First I've done 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k\log_x 2 )(k+1)\log_x 2}=\frac{4n}{n+1} $$
Then:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)\log^2_x 2 }=\frac{4n}{n+1} $$
I multiplied by the logarithm:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{4n}{n+1}\log^2_x 2  $$ 
So: 
$$\ 1-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{4n}{n+1}\log^2_x 2 $$ 
And this results in $x=4$ (when it is supposed to be $\frac{1}{4}$).

When approaching it again(found my mistake in this approach), I just separated each term of the sum like $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\log_x 2^k}-\frac{1}{\log_x (2^k\cdot 2)}$$ 
and it resulted in 
$$\ \frac{1}{\log_x 2}- \frac{1}{\log_x (2^n\cdot2)}=\frac{4n}{n+1} $$ 
Which is the same as:
$$\ \frac{1}{\log_x 2}- \frac{1}{(n+1)\log_x 2}=\frac{4n}{n+1} $$ 
And then I got: 
$$\ 1- \frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{4n}{n+1}\log_x 2 $$
That really got confused due to the difference from the one above it. And this gives $x=16$.

Could you please tell me where am I mistaking and why aren't those $2$ above the same? Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to prove this false statement?

Comment: I don't think it's false, is it? The book where I found it didn't have any mistakes so far, and I've gone through quite some of it. x is supposed to be 1/4 so that the equality is true. And I got x=4 and x=16 so far...

Comment: I mean, plug in $x=2$ and $n=1$ and the statement is blatently false.  (The left side is less than 1, and the right side is greater than 1)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I forgot to say where x takes its values, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You got $4$ because you took the positive square root, while you should take the negative one because $\ln x < 0$ (because $0<x<1$).

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase what I'm asking.  *What are you trying to do?*

Comment: That was it @Cauchy. Thank you!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt the goal was to find x, but I already got the answer i was looking for, thank you as well for the fast response.

Comment: Okay and no problem :-)

Comment: Straightened up your logs a bit.

Comment: @mathreadler They drive me nuts lol

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Just try to see it as a joke ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(log_x 2^k )*log_x (2^k*2))}=\\
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(log_x 2 )\times(k+1)(log_x 2)}=\\
\frac{1}{(log_x 2)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\\
\frac{1}{(log_x 2)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+1)-(k)}{k(k+1)}=\\
\frac{1}{(log_x 2)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}=\\\frac{1}{(log_x 2)^2}(1-\frac{1}{n+1})=\\\to \\
\frac{1}{(log_x 2)^2}(\frac{n}{n+1})=\frac{4n}{n+1}$$ simplify $ \frac{n}{n+1}$
$$\frac{1}{(log_x 2)^2}=4\\(log_x 2)^2=\frac14\\log_x 2=\pm\frac12\to \\
\begin{cases}log_x 2=\frac12 \to & \log_2 x=2 \to x=2^2=4\\log_x 2=-\frac12\to & \log_2 x=-2 \to x=2^{-2}=\frac14 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you, added just after i posted that 0<x<1, so the only solution is 1/4.